# iMessage isn't "delivered"

Tags: iphone, messages

This morning I was trying to send a text to my friend but it didn't say delivered on the bottom of it. I then tried to call her and all it did was ring for a long time before going to voicemail. Does that mean her phone is off? Am I blocked? Or the connection just sucks? This is the first time this ever happened, so I'm just trying to make sure I shouldn't be worried.

Comment: The phone may be off, the battery dead, no cell/wifi signal (or both), etc.